# ARPlane in ARkit is diffusing contents of a web kit view but not displaying properly

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am Diffusing contents of other views in arplane in ARkit .but when I attempt this for web kit view then it isn't diffusing contents (html) loaded by a url in WebKit view.